# Facebook Android sdk and Facebook app overlapping

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have developed an Android game that integrates facebook SDK for checking if one has liked and sharing results.

I heard from my mate that he had problem that made him unable to use the like for reward feature on my app, so I decided to install facebook app myself to check out the problem.

For some reason if I am trying to access the fb api reading data from URL "https://api.facebook.com/method/pages.isFan?format=json&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&page_id=PAGE_ID" it opens up facebook app on Android which only flashes and then turns off.. How can I avoid this or is there better way to check if one has liked my page in order to give him reward?

Comment: how are you reading the facebook api? Is it using the function request which is found in facebook android sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used the Facebook API, but the Facebook app is probably opening because it's listening for broadcast Intents to "api.facebook.com". You could explicitly send the intent to a browser package instead, but this isn't a good solution as there are many browsers.

I would try to do a HTTPS request using a Loader to fetch and parse the json. Have you tried this yet?

I can't paste any code right now, sorry.

Comment: The problem was invalid key on facebook app page, but because of your helpful answer have the bounty! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, glad you fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

From your comment to above Answer , Glad to know that you solved your problem,
Here is the answer for your Question

> is there better way to check if one has liked my page

You can surely use **FQL** - Facebook Query Language to do this, given under the developer documentation in Facebook site.

There are Two different table

1.[Page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/) - where you can get all the detail about the page
 2.[Page_Fan](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page_fan/) - which you can use to know the fan-id for the page